# What can I infer about a linear model if I change how the dimension data is aggregated?

Tags: confidence-interval, linear-model, inference

What concepts (if any) should I study to better understand this?

I have a dataset with billions of records. It's a rough proxy for a subset of traffic on a nationwide network.  I have location and site information with the proxy data.  I also have true values for traffic on a per site level, but no location data with those true values.  I created nationwide heatmaps of the proxy data, and my goal is to be able to take those bins in the heatmap, and predict true traffic with some confidence interval.

On a site-level, there's a linear relationship between the proxy data and the real values, with some significant variance.  But in each bin in the heatmap, the sum of the proxy values may be from few or many different sites, and each site has its traffic spread out over thousands or more bins in the heatmap.  Consequently, the linear model that relates the values on a per site basis covers a range ~20x larger than the model I'd need to relate them per bin.

My question is: **Can I infer anything about the relationship on a per bin basis in my heatmap based on a known linear model that relates the proxy and truth on a per site basis?**